# If there is a right calculus of fractions, $L$-local morphisms are pullback stable

Tags: ct.category-theory

$\require{AMScd}$ Let $L : {\cal A} \leftrightarrows {\cal B} : R$ be a reflection (so $R$ is fully faithful). I'm trying to prove that if the class $\Sigma_L$ of morphisms in $\cal A$ inverted by $L$ has a [right calculus of fractions](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/calculus+of+fractions), then $\Sigma_L$ is pullback-stable (--of course provided finite limits exist; long story short: it is enough to prove this when $s\in\Sigma_L$ is pulled back along an arrow in $\Sigma_L^\perp$).

How can I prove this?

There is only a small step I'm missing: start with a pullback square
$$
\begin{CD}
A @>>m'> B\\
@VpVV @VVsV\\
C @>>m> D
\end{CD}
$$
where $s\in\Sigma_L$, $m\in\Sigma_L^\perp$; I claim that $p\in\Sigma_L$. The first condition of a calculus of fractions ensures that this diagram can be extended to
$$
\begin{CD}
X @>t>> A @>>m'> B\\
@Vs'VV @VpVV @VVsV\\
C @=C @>>m> D
\end{CD}
$$
where $s'\in\Sigma_L$, so that $p\in\Sigma_L$ if and only if $t\in\Sigma_L$ (the composition $m't$ is the arrow $u$ such that the outer rectangle commutes). We then have to prove that $t\in\Sigma_L$. $(\Sigma_L,\Sigma_L^\perp)$-factor $t$ as the composition $m'''s''$, let's see that $m''\in\Sigma_L$.

This is where I stop.